# How do I center an absolutely positioned element?

Tags: html, css, css-position, centering

```
div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: yellow;
    z-index: 99;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I have a div pop message, it will be on top layer and position middle of page.

however if i set `position:absolute; z-index:99;` it will be on top but `margin:0 auto;` wont work.

how can i keep it on top of layer and also display at middle?

Comment: `top:50%;` and `right:50%` add those properties

Comment: instead of position:absolute; - use position:relative;

Comment: relative cant not overlayer

Comment: if you need to use position:absolute; then add the rules: left:0; and right:0 and margin:auto; - that will keep it centered

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Centering an element with `position: absolute;` applied works by using two nested elements ([**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Jnbu/1/)).

1. The **first element** will be **positioned absolutely** to place it above all other elements
2. The **second element** just works like you would expect it: Use **`margin: 0 auto;` to center** it.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outer-div">
    <div class="inner-div">
        <p>This is a modal window being centered.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.outer-div {
    position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    z-index: 13;

    /*
     * Setting all four values to 0 makes the element as big
     * as its next relative parent. Usually this is the viewport.
     */
}

.inner-div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: khaki;
}
```